# DOM element visiility and requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I was reading an article on [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/) that gave an example about scrolling through a webpage and checking an array of DOM elements offsetTop's to see if they should be visible.

The article says the best practice way of doing this would be to update a variable with the windows current offset top every time a scroll event is fired. When the first scroll event is fired, it triggers the requestAnimationFrame process of checking offsetTop's of the DOM elements. This decouples the visibility logic from the scroll event.

While I understand the benefit of certainly decoupling these two processes (since the scroll event could be called hundreds of times a second), I can't see the benefit of running the visibility logic every 16ms after the first scroll event, regardless of whether the user has continued to move or not..

Can someone please explain what part of the process I'm missing here?

Comment: I'd say that depends on the visibility logic. What is it intended to do?

Comment: It is supposed to cycle through an array of selectors, then determine if they are on screen by checking the windows top offset against the top/bottom offsets of the element and then add a class to make it visible if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's well explained in the article.

> What else can we do? Well for one thing we are constantly running
> requestAnimationFrame and that’s not necessary if we haven’t just
> scrolled since nothing will have changed. To fix that we have the
> onScroll initiate the requestAnimationFrame
>
> Now whenever we scroll we will try and call requestAnimationFrame, but
> if one is already requested we don’t initiate another. This is an
> important optimization, since the browser will stack all the repeated
> rAF requests and we would be back to a situation with more calls to
> update than we need.
>
> Thanks to this setup we no longer need to call requestAnimationFrame
> at the top of update because we know it will only be requested when
> one or more scroll events has taken place. We also no longer need the
> kick off call at the bottom, either, so let’s update accordingly:

```
var latestKnownScrollY = 0,
    ticking = false;

function onScroll() {
    latestKnownScrollY = window.scrollY;
    if (!ticking) {
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    ticking = true;
}
function update() {
    ticking = false; // reset the tick so we can capture the next onScroll

    var currentScrollY = latestKnownScrollY;

    // Do visibilty logic and animation here
}
```

So, "*regardless of whether the user has continued to move or not*" is not really true. `update` is only called during (or a littlebit after) the scroll, and at a browser-choosen frame rate instead of a rate of hundreds of events per seconds.

Comment: OK, so am I right in saying that the scroll event fires an exponential amount of times, and it also schedules an animation frame for whenever the browser finds it most convenient, unless one has already been scheduled (which is what our flag is keeping check of)?

Comment: Yes, that sounds good. Though I'm not sure whether browsers really do fire `scroll` events at such a high rate, they know there are many implementations that don't decouple their animations.

Comment: Thank you very much Bergi, you've been really helpful!

Comment: Note that this is actuaply completely useless: scroll events fire only in painting frames, i.e calling requestAnimationFrame inside a scroll event handler will schedule the callback to the same event loop's frame, almost like a microtask.

Comment: @Kaiido Are you sure there (or has this changed)? I could swear I remember scroll events firing faster than an animation frame loop. Notice this answer is from 2012 though :-)

Comment: I can't swear it always has been like that, and I remember I was also surprised the first time I found this out a few years ago, myself convinced scroll events did fire a lot faster, but yes, I'm sure about this: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering step 11.8 "run the scroll steps", and a few sub-steps later 11.13 "run the animation frame callbacks". Actually I think where the confusion came from is that the "wheel" event (or whatever its names were) do fire at high frequency. Scroll doesn't.